# AngularJS select box generated from object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, refactoring

I am refactoring some code, and want to change an array of code/name objects to be named objects. I want to do this so I can use it for equality tests. The old way was to compare the code directly...

```
if(current.addressCode === "1"){ ... }
```

But I would prefer to do it like this...

```
if(current.addressCode === types.student.address.letter.code){ ... }
```

The old object looks like this...

```
student{
  address: [
    {code: "0", name: "Select proof of address"},
    {code: "1", name: "Letter"},
    {code: "3", name: "Photograph"}
  ],
  id: [
    {code: "0", name: "Select type of ID"},
    {code: "1", name: "Passport"},
    {code: "2", name: "Driving Licence"}
  ]
}
```

So I want my new object to look like this...

```
student: {
  address: {
    select: {code: "0", name: "Select proof of address"},
    letter: {code: "1", name: "Letter"},
    photograph: {code: "3", name: "Photograph"},
  },
  id: {
    select: {code: "0", name: "Select type of ID"},
    passport: {code: "1", name: "Passport"},
    drivingLicense: {code: "2", name: "Driving Licence"},
  }
}
```

Where I am stuck, is I don't know how to generate a select element in angular js from this object which used to be generated from the old structure like this...

```
<select ng-model="current.addressCode" ng-options="t.code as t.name for t in student.address"></select>
```

How can I use the new object to generate a select form element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<select ng-model="current.addressCode" ng-options="value.code as value.name for (key,value) in student.address"></select>
```

Comment: Any idea how to order the select by code? Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UPWKe/1/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654259/angular-js-order-select-using-key-value