# Angular JS order select using key/value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just asked about generating a select from key/value map instead of array: [AngularJS select box generated from object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653307/angularjs-select-box-generated-from-object)

That is all working fine now: http://jsfiddle.net/UPWKe/1/

```
<select ng-model="current.addressCode" ng-options="value.code as value.name for (key, value) in student.address | orderBy: 'code'"</select>
```

... and js ...

```
$scope.student = {
    address: {
        select: {
            code: "0",
            name: "Select proof of address"
        },
        letter: {
            code: "1",
            name: "Letter"
        },
        photograph: {
            code: "3",
            name: "Photograph"
        }
    },
```

But the only thing missing, is how to order the select items.

How can I order select items in a select box generated from key/value map in angularjs?

Comment: use angular filter i think

Comment: might have to write your own, but it's not that hard

Comment: @kangoroo please elaborate, how I could use a filter to sort this? What would I filter?

Comment: well, actually you can probably use OrderBy as well

Comment: @kangoroo I did try using orderBy, but I could not figure out how to get it to work. I would be grateful of any suggestions...

Comment: @BillyMoon I have updated my answer to include the solution using a filter as well.

Comment: @BillyMoon There is no out-of-box way to do that on an object. You need to convert it to a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1**: You can use another array to store the order of the fields. For this you would need to use `ng-repeat` in place of `ng-options`:

```
$scope.studentAddressFields = [
    "select",
    "letter",
    "photograph"
]
```

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="current.addressCode">
    <option ng-repeat="field in studentAddressFields" 
    value="student.address[field]['code']">
        {{student.address[field]['name']}}
    </option>
</select>
```

**Solution 2**: Using a filter:

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="current.addressCode" ng-options="code as details.name 
for (code, details) in student.address | getOrdered">
</select>
```

Filter:

```
myApp.filter('getOrdered', function() {
    return function(input) {
        var ordered = {};
        for (var key in input){            
            ordered[input[key]["code"]] = input[key];
        }           
        return ordered;
    };
});
```

Comment: to make it a general solution, and much more re-usable - is there any way to make `code` a variable - so something like... `(key, val) in someObject | getOrdered:"code"`

Comment: Solution 2 does not work correctly. If you have code 2, 10, 15 they will be in the order 10,15,2 and not 2,10,15 even if you remove quotes from code values.