# How to order Map without changing the return object Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JVEF2T63YiBMPphXwV3G?p=preview) that is trying to sort a collection of objects for display. The map looks like...

```
{
 test1:{
   name:'Cccccc',
   title:'Aaaaaa'
 }
}
```

I would like to order this list by title using a filter, however, the following seems to fail...

```
 this.drawers = $filter('orderBy')(this.drawers, 'title', false);
```

I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654259/angular-js-order-select-using-key-value) to a similar question, however, this does not appear to apply to my scenario because it changes the structure of the object returned from the filter. Does anyone know how I would write a custom filter to handle this?

Comment: You are trying to sort an object (`this.drawers = {}`). Please change your data structure to be an Array (`this.drawers = []`).

Comment: I can't change the structure

Comment: Sorry the whole reason I can't change structure is that we use the structure to, among other things, ensure the collection is a set. So it would be extremely hard to change the structure. So I would like to try and find a solution with this structure.

Comment: Slightly off from your question, but underscore.js has some great ways of doing these sorts of things